# Is it possible to move a ADX On-Premise portal to Online portal keeping functionality intact?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, adxstudio-portals

I have an On-premise Dynamics 365 v8 org on my machine and I have configured on-premise ADX portals on it. The portal is heavily customized with quite a lot of changes made to the aspx page and almost no changes on the Web-Template side of things. There are a lot of custom aspx pages that do advanced calculations and record CRUD as well.

Is it possible to migrate the entire portal to the online Portal Capabilities on an online Dynamics 365 v9 org without losing out on current functionality?

As a follow-up, is it possible to update records using JS on the portal? If yes, how do we encapsulate it so the end-user cannot view the JS logic used? If not, is there a way to perform CRUD operations from the portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to migrate the entire portal to the online Portal Capabilities on an online Dynamics 365 v9 org without losing out on current functionality?

The short answer is no, you will not be able to migrate the entire portal, as is, given the changes you have made to ASPX pages. Online portals does not let you host custom ASPX files. You would need to re-implement all custom ASPX pages in other ways such as in Liquid code, CRM plugins, and client-side JavaScript.

> As a follow-up, is it possible to update records using JS on the portal? If yes, how do we encapsulate it so the end-user cannot view the JS logic used? If not, is there a way to perform CRUD operations from the portal?

You would either have to:

- Submit the data using entity forms, and use CRM plugins to adjust the submitted data
- Build a companion web application that is deployed elsewhere, such as an Azure App Service, where your form is submitted via client-side JavaScript to it using cross-domain AJAX requests.